# Unrecognized selector sent to instance error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, scenekit

Consider this code:

```
SCNNode *someNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
Piece *piece = (Piece *)someNode;
[piece pick];
```

Where Piece is a sub-class of SCNNode and contains a method called pick. Xcode is returning this error:

```
[SCNNode pick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Can someone tell what is wrong with my code?

**Edit:**

I tried this as well. Same problem.

```
- (id)initPieceWithNode:(SCNNode *)node {

    if (self = [super init]) {
         self = (Piece *)[node copy];
    }

return self;
}
```

Comment: `someNode` is not a `Piece` object, it's a `SCNNode` object. You can't simply cast a base class instance into a subclass instance an expect it to work.

Comment: @rmaddy but its returning `pick` is not a method of `SCNNode` whereas OP has defined it in `SCNNode`

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala No, `pick` is a method of `Piece`, not `SCNNode`.

Comment: Thank you @rmaddy. And yes, pick is a method of Piece. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, then you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're casting a SCNNode into a Piece, you're not creating a Piece object.  If you convert, the method won't appear magically in a SCNNode.

You should do something like :

```
Piece *piece = [Piece pieceWithNode:someNode];
```

And exemple :

```
+ (Piece *)pieceWithNode:(SCNNode *)aNode {
     Piece *newPiece = [Piece new];

     newPiece.property1 = aNode.propertyX
     newPiece.property2 = aNode.propertyY
     ...

     return newPiece;
}
```

This is the best way to do that.

**EDIT 2 :**
*According to comments :*

```
Piece *piece = [Piece new]; 
[piece pick];
```

It's enougth

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me how that pieceWithNode method look like? I am an absolute beginner in Objective-C :)

Comment: Ho I don't know, I'm giving you the way you should do that. I don't know SCNNode and Piece classes so I can't tell you if the method name is right. Was an explication on how you should do that.

Comment: I have written the Piece class myself, while SCNNode is Apple's class for Scene Kit nodes. Piece is a sub class of SCNNode. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I am trying to get it to work, if it does, I'll mark your answer correct.

Comment: So in your Piece class, create a + method names pieceWithNode:(SCNNode *)aNode;  - Then inside it, read the properties you need in the node and copy them in a brand new created Piece object, then return the Piece object.  Hope it guides you on the correct way

Comment: If the object is the wrong type then it's the wrong type and converting it to the right type doesn't really sound like a viable solution.

Comment: I've not told to convert (cast) it. I tell to do like a `objectWithDataFromDictionary`.    You read the basic object to add the data inside the new object, with additional method / properties.   Like you do when creating a new `NSManagedObject` from a Dictionary or other.

Comment: But that's not how handling a polymorphic object generally works is it.  You get passed the base type and you perform type checks to see if it's a derived type.  If it is a derived type then you do additional stuff with the object, you don't convert it to a subclass as you suggest.

Comment: Yes you do: `Piece *piece = [Piece pieceWithNode:someNode];`  This is conversion.

Comment: `Piece *piece = (Piece *)node;`   this is convertion

Comment: No.  That's is an improper and broken conversion.  I would suggest that **no** conversion takes place in the handler, correct or not.

Comment: in the original question the user is creating the node himself. So there is no need to allocate an `SCNNode` and then a `Piece` to copy the just-created node. Just allocate a `Piece` with `Piece *piece = [[Piece alloc] init]; [piece pick];`

Answer (score 1):

if `Piece` is a subclass of `SCNNode` then

```
   Piece *piece = [[Piece alloc] init];
   [piece pick];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling a polymorphic type then you should query the exact type of the object and perform actions upon that object that are appropriate for that type.

For example you have:

```
@interface SCNNode : NSObject
- (void)baseMethod;
@end

@interface Piece : SCNNode
- (void)derivedMethod;
@end
```

Then the handling code should behave something like this:

```
- (void)doSomethingWithNode:(SCNNode *)node
{
    [node baseMethod];
    if ([node isKindOfClass:[Piece class]]) {
        [node derivedMethod];
    }
}
```

It is not appropriate for the handling code to convert the base type to a derived type as I doubt it's in a position to provide the additional attributes of the object.  If you are converting then something is wrong elsewhere.